# What is the best way to make a data grid in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yhwx.png)

Good evening everyone!

Part of my requirements for the app I am building has me creating a data grid similar to the example linked. I have spent the entire day searching google and this site in order to find the best way to get started in swift. I have read so far that both a table view and a collection view could work, but that a collection view is preferred. My data grid doesn't necessarily have to be scrollable but the data does need to be editable. I don't have much experience using either tableviews or collectionviews and I'm looking for the simplest implementation without relying on a third party dependency. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We have open sourced our datagrid component that was designed to do this: http://www.ioscomponents.com/Home/Buy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know your experience level, I will explain at a basic level - my apologies in advance if it's too basic :) A `UITableView` displays rows of data, while a `UICollectionView` displays cells in a grid.

So, at first, a `UICollectionView` might appear to be the better option. But as always, things get complicated pretty quickly :) For example, are you going to implement your `UICollectionView` as one cell for the whole row, or are you going to implement a cell per column in your table of data? And if you implement cells per column of data, how are you going to handle the different types of cells you might (or might not) need for each column?

There are multiple decisions that might need to be made, and only you know the answers to a lot of these :)

But the simpler option probably is to go with `UITableView` and that's what I'd suggest if you are new to both `UITableView`s and `UICollectionView`. Try out a `UITableView`-based approach first and if that doesn't work, or you see limitations, then try a `UICollectionView`. The experience you had in building the `UITableView` will help you in moving on to `UICollectionView` anyway :)

Comment: I have been wondering the same question about how it would work with a collection view with cells per column of data. It sounds like it could get pretty complicated indeed! for the tableview it would involve creating a custom cell that could hold a label for each 'column' correct?

Comment: Yep, try a `UITableView` first - you might find it doesn't work for your needs because you need text fields and not all of them will fit on one row. Then you might have to re-think your UI anyway ... Best thing is to always try it out so that you know the issues you'll run into and so can do a different iteration :)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help! I will try and see what progress I make.

Comment: Great :) And if the above answer helped, please mark it as "correct". And if you run into any issues, do feel free to ping me when you create a new question and I'll take a look and answer if I am able to help.